# How do I render this code in block/node page?

Tags: nodes

```
print render($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['rc_core_item_avail_form']);
```

I tried putting this into a node in the Omega theme and also in a block directly but nothing at all. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use that code in a node or in a block, since in both the cases the `$page` variable is not available. It seems that code is taken from an implementation of [hook_page_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) or adapted from code used by an implementation of `hook_page_alter()`. In fact:

- `hook_page_alter()` receives `$page` as argument
- The documentation for `hook_page_alter()` shows that, for a node page, `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']` is the content of a node body

If rc_core_item_avail_form is a node field, in a block you could use code similar to the following one.

```
// Load the currently shown node.
$node = menu_get_object();

// Render the field.
$elements = field_view_field('node', $node, 'rc_core_item_avail_form');
print render($elements);
```

In the case the field could not be visible to every user, but you want to make that field visible to every user when it is shown in the block, then I would use the following code.

```
// Load the currently shown node.
$node = menu_get_object();

// Render the field.
$elements = field_view_field('node', $node, 'rc_core_item_avail_form');
$elements['#access'] = TRUE;
print render($elements);
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows nothing?

Comment: You should say exactly where you are trying the code, since _into a node_ is too vague.

Comment: I have put it into a add new block section and inserted the code, it should show a calendar form block, but it is not working? as this code : print render($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['rc_core_item_avail_form']); seems like it needs to get the NID of the node and then print out the form, but currently the new converted code does not do that, any clue? thank you

Comment: You still didn't say where you are using that code. What do you mean by "new block section"? Are you using it in a template file? If it is so, in which template file are you using it?

Comment: sorry, I am not that familiar with the drupal saying, I am using it in http://www.site.com/admin/structure/block/add, and it is not working, any clue? please let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: As I said, you cannot use it there: "You cannot use that code in a node or in a block." Even if you would be using PHP for creating a block, the `$page` variable is not available. The code I shown should work, if the block is visible in a node page, and the PHP filter is used when creating the block.

Comment: I used omega theme and inserted in the html.tpl but not working, and tried using the node.tpl also not working. :( sorry I am not good at this thing. any clue to solve it?